# Express and URL rewriting | HTML5 history

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm trying to build a simple server to serve a single HTML page where all the logics are
handled by Angular. As far as I'm using the HTML5 history mode I'm able to navigate 
through standard URLs.

Now, to make this work I need to enable URL rewriting. I tried with this bunch of lines and
although return always the correct HTML page, the URL vary and does not keep the initial
value. For example /popular should load index.html and leave the URL /popular so that the
JS logic can load the desired page.

Here follows the express code.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
}); 

app.get("/*", function(req, res, next){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: The code above should work (and, in fact, it does). You write in a comment below that you are getting redirects; I doubt these are generated by Express, since nothing seems to suggest it'd have a reason to generate them. So perhaps Angular is changing the URL, you're using a proxy in front of Node, or the code above isn't complete.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the root directory for relative filenames.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html', { root: __dirname+'/dist' });
});
```

Comment: With this line of code a possible URL /popular is still redirected to the URL /. Even more I can see that I have to add some folders like /images or /scripts to not being considered. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you follow the example [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/server/server.js) a 'static' folder is created to handle all the pages assets so you only need to handle a single path /static instead of handling /img /scripts etc. separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna try this out.